# Is there a way to exclude International E-road network?

Tags: here-api

I need to know if there is some kind of way for here-maps API maybe not to exclude but rather display International European road as a standard road? What I mean, is rather gmaps approach, where examples like E261, E30, E75, E28 are presented in a A2, A10, A13, A15 way (examples are not exact, pasted randomly).

Cheers

Comment: Not exactly understood the requirement, maybe you could share some screenshots of your expectation. In general the labels are fixed on the Map tile, you could try disabling the labels and adding them separately by querying the Meta Info layer but would be an overhead.

Comment: Well, excuse me, maybe it did sound like out of the box. What I meant was: your routing service calculates routes between two waypoints, in response it gives list of routes on which the vehicle should travel. And here comes my question, is it possible to get those routes in a distinct manner? In HERE api, I get: NU9, A7, A8, K9652, K9657, B10, A65, B9, A35, A34, N31, N31 but is it actually possible to get those routes in all A or B notation? This behavior is default in google-maps, I think. When I calculate routes with gmap, I get for example: A2, A10, B12, etc

Comment: Maybe not only in A and B notation, there are some Ns too, but it is still a default behaviour from google maps. Don't you guys have some kind of compatibility schemes?

Comment: https://imgur.com/wTDP58A

if you may open, you will notice two notations, I would rather like to get A3 in the routing service than E40

Comment: can support answer me?

Answer (score 0):

Also the list of the route descriptions is using the details from the compiled map. There is no way to exclude either the European nor the country naming for highways. This is fixed.